# Corrupt Xcode project? - A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: xcode

So, i've read all the questions with no results.

I've also created a new Xcode project to test my provisioning/cert setup. Compile and runs on device just fine.

I'm beginning to think my Xcode project is somehow corrupt now? I did read that somewhere on here but can't find the reference now.

Assuming it is corrupt, what's the best way to resolve? Can I repair or should I just create a new Xcode project and start fresh?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just fixed this after a whole day of troubleshooting.

What I did was rollback to a previously working project, and extract the contents of the `.xcodeproj`. With these files I went to my most recent project (broken) and replaced the `.xcodeproj` package with the older files.

Nasty, but worked like a charm. Hope it helps somebody else.